# Trouble with bone constraints and deformations

Tags: rigging, constraints

I am trying to create something with this effect, but the instructions are very unclear about applying the bone constraints. It has to do with copy rotation and the damped track constraint, but I don't know how to use them. I am trying to fix these odd deformations in the shoulder area of my character.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve
[image: what I'm trying to achieve]

Here's what I have so far

[image: what I have so far]

Here you can see the awful shoulder deformations I'm trying to fix

[image: bad deformations]

I know another user had a similar question, but the answer failed to explain the usage behind the constraints used. In fact, the example animation in which I'm trying to achieve is taken from an answer to another question similar to mine. [Shoulder Deformations Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41539/shoulder-deformations)

Comment: I highly recommend viewing the tutorial series by Nathan Vegdahl, [Humane Rigging](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3J-XN38EnhQ&list=PLE211C8C41F1AFBAB). It will teach you everything you need to know about rigging and the tutorials are well done.

Comment: I found that none of the videos had to do with rigging humanoid figures. I already knew most of the information he says. What I'm asking for specifically in this question is how to fix my deforming shoulder using the constraints used in the example animation

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41539/shoulder-deformations and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41695/blending-bone-weights and https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=shoulder%20deformation

Comment: The first link is the very place where I got the example animation and could not find an explanation for the bone constraints. The second link deals with vertex groups and bone weighting which I already know how to do. The last link is a collection of other solutions that do not answer my question. Basically what I'm asking for is how to set up the constraints to achieve the result in the example animation.

Comment: Good news! You can download and study the exact rig you're talking about here: [https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/7093](https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/7093)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution is tho set all bones constrained with a copy rotation, varying the influence setting from none (Shoulder) to full (hand).

[image]

Comment: what are each of the bones constrained to? I think this is the part I am having trouble with

Comment: every bone is constrained to the "Kontrol" (non-deforming, circle custom shaped) bone. In my example the hand bone has full constraint, the forearm bone (selected) has 0.66 influence, and the upper arm bone has 0.33 influence. So when I rotated the Kontrol bone by 90 degrees, the hand rotated 90, the forearm 60 and the upper arm 30 degrees (aaproximately). the shoulder stays still for balancing the upper arm vertices.