# Arm rig with natural shoulder deformation

Tags: rigging

Part two in the answer to this post describes exactly what I want to achieve for the shoulder deformation but it doesn't explain how to do it:

[Shoulder deformations](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41539/shoulder-deformations)

I downloaded the example Sintel rig and I can't find which controller is being moved to achieve movement of both the arm and the shoulder. It's quite a complex rig and I want to keep mine as simple as possible.

I see somebody else asked the same question here but with no solid solution -

[Shoulder Movement following the arm](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65849/shoulder-movement-following-the-arm)

Any other suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, could you pleas share the Sintel rig?

Comment: To move the shoulder and the arm, both bones (the shoulder bone and the arm bone) are animated.

Comment: Hello again @moonboots Here is the Sintel rig - blendswap.com/blends/view/7093.

Comment: @Leander oh I see! I didn't realise it was an animation but that would make sense