# Should Twist Deform Problem

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm quite having problems with the twisting of the shoulders I don't know if its the weight, or something about the IK.
This is my character.
https://www.mediafire.com/?5903hn3cjqt9n8d
[image]

Comment: what is the difference between this and your other question http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41539/shoulder-deformations ?

Comment: There is no difference but It's difficult for me to follow the instruction he's giving maybe a tutorial for that clip.

Comment: Nevermind I'll just delete this question clueless

Comment: This is not a tutorial request site. If you do need help understanding the answer to the linked question, try and identify what part specifically that you are having trouble with and ask a question about that.

Comment: For a general intro to rigging in blender you should check out humane rigging (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-0oBXJZwQE&list=PL3wFcRXImVPOQpi-wi7uriXBkykXVUntv)