# How to setup IK Arms with upper and lower arm twist bones?

Tags: rigging, armature, inverse-kinematics

I have two bones for the upper arm, and two bones for the forearm. This is to assist in proper deformations when rotating the elbow and wrist, respectively. (ie: Using forward kinematics, if I want to twist the elbow, I simply twist just the 2nd bone in the upper arm; to twist the hand, I simply twist the 2nd bone in the forearm)

How do I setup Inverse Kinematics using these bones? I don't want the movement of the elbow pole target to rotate the 1st upper arm bone and ruin the shoulder deformation, and same goes for the forearm/wrist. I'm having trouble figuring out the rig setup.

EDIT: The main problem is that my upper arm bones are not aligned along a straight path from shoulder to elbow, due to how the arm mesh is modeled. [image]

Comment: Similar like this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41550/7777. You can even use BBones if you won't use it outside of Blender.

Comment: Unfortunately that solution may not be the way, due to how my upper arm is rigged.

Comment: I suggest re-rigging that arm and placing the shoulder in the correct place. You won't get good results with this.