# Ugly deformation for wrist and shoulder with IK

Tags: inverse-kinematics

New here.

I've been implementing some basic IK stuff for a rig of mine. The arms, the legs, etc. Overall I'm happy with how it's been going, but there is a problem.

Whenever I go to push the rig's arms into a more complicated position (in this case, a casual "hands on hips" sort of pose) I end up with some very twisty deformation at the wrists and shoulders.

[image]

[image]

There's an option to "preserve volume" for the mesh on the armature modifier, and that would be a decent enough band-aid except I need to export the model into Unreal Engine, which won't accept modifiers.

I think this might be a common issue for newbs like me, but I haven't found a clear solution online yet. Hopefully someone here has some suggestions! Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Here's a PasteAll link to the .blend file if anyone wants to take a direct look: [Blend File Link.](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50890)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shoulder deformations](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41539/shoulder-deformations)

Comment: You need twist bones, for both humerus and forearm.  Shoulder is rotating in Y axis when it shouldn't (fixable with locks, if not using a pole.)  But fixing it will leave your elbow in wrong position, for which you need a humerus twist.  Same for wrist: your hand bone is at too strong local Y rotation compared to forearm, but can't change forearm without breaking the elbow's angle lock-- unless you add a forearm twist.  (Weights, and likely bone placement, are not ideal either, but the twists are the major issue right now.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the elbow, it looks like your arm is pivoting on itself. Think of like a rope you hold tight with one hand and you twist with your other hand. It's what's happening here.
A solution for that would be to lock the bone's rotation on its Y axis. Either through a Limit Rotation constraint, either in the bone's Inverse Kinematics panel:
[image: demo pic]

Otherwise, understand that bones do only one thing: rotating vertices around. The "preserve volume" does help to keep the volumes, but it doesn't do any miracles. When two bones rotate on each other, there's always a point when some vertices go the wrong way.

And that's why we use "[Corrective Shape Keys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3JWNIkwBZ8)". Just make some of those and you will be fine. Also, there are some addons out there (like [that one](https://en.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Animation/Corrective_Shape_Key)) that might help you create your CSP faster. But start manually, so that you learn how it works and understand how everything works.

Comment: Took me a minute to find the right configuration, but I think it's looking good! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

[image: rig]
[image: modifiers]
Similar to L0Locks answer an alternative is to add a copy rotation modifier with 50% influence to the next bone up the chain. By setting the influence to 50% the rotation will blend with the rotated target bone providing a smoother transition. Definitely not perfect but good for a quick fix. Note: you may have to play with the axis invert setting depending on your rigs orientation.