# Bones flip out when posed using inverse kinematics

Tags: armature, bones, inverse-kinematics

Okay so I have rigged many armatures in my time in blender, and this problem happens from time to time but its usually slight enough to ignore, but not this time.
So I have a rig made for a human, with IK constraints and bones to manipulate them with. The constraints are applied to the shins, hips, upper, and lower arms. When I use the IK bones for the shins like lift them up and forwards it spasms and contorts twisting around.

Now I did remove the parents to all IK bones, and I just doubled check it before posting this. Also I don't know if this is part of the problem, but when I just raise the shins up the knees fly far out to the sides instead of just bending.

Any ideas?

Comment: Rig the legs like this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21379/how-to-ik-rig-legs/21385#21385 using only 1 IK constraint and a Pole target. Similar with arms. After you have that working add bones for twisting: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41550/7777

Comment: I have done that before, but usually used it on animal rigs, will try it here. But I don't understand why the original method I used doesn't do the same thing with the arms?

Comment: From the description I am unsure how is your rig exactly setup, maybe a picture or a shared .blend would help, I don't know what you mean by original method. My suspicion is it is something you should no do and does not work, but I can't tell what might be the issue. So I just linked a setup that works, but if you add more detail into the question I might be able to help with what you have so hopefully you don't have to re-design your whole bone setup.

Comment: please share your file (at least the armature): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/