# How to do a correct shoulder deformation?

Tags: rigging

So, I’m rigging a character in Blender and I’m having a bit of trouble with the shoulder deformation. Namely the region under the arm as seen here:

[image]

I was trying to replicate this I saw here:

[Shoulder deformations](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41539/shoulder-deformations)

But the instructions aren’t very clear and I can’t seem to download the file from BlendSwap as the site just keeps giving me an error every time I try to login.

So, I was hoping someone here with some rigging experience could help me out with this. I’m just scratching my head here at this point.

Blend:

[image]

Comment: Don't see what you want to do exactly? Have you tried to raise an arm without moving the clavicle?

Comment: try to decrease the influence of the upper arm for the armpit

Comment: I think this is closer to what in should be in real life, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what's bothering you is what's happening on the armpit, switch to *Weight Paint* mode, select a *Blend* > *Subtract* brush, *Strength* 1, activate the *2D Falloff* option in order to paint through, and paint.

[image]

Comment: That's much better actually, but it still looks strange. Like, imagine the character is holding something over their head, the arm looks like it pops out.

Comment: In that case you need to rotate the soulder a bit

Comment: I changed the picture on the opening post with the weight fixes. So is that how it's suppose to behave when you lift the arm up to hold something over the head? It looks like shoudler bit is bulging out a bit too much.

Comment: it doesn't look too bad, and anyway, if you can't get what you want with your bones, you need to create some shapekeys that will be triggered by drivers etc... To get something realistic is not easy anyway

Comment: Hmm...I honestly forgot about creating some corrective shapekeys. Will do that, I think that just might fix the whole problem. Thanks for the help.